# How to change color of the UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uiimageview, uiimage

I am trying to change the color of the particular UIImage but when i search in the internet i ended up with result of changing tint color of the UIImage, If i change the tint color it will overlap the entire image with the Given color this not what i needed. Can someone please help me to do this? This may look like doing the photo editing in the Photoshop or sketch. I have attached the image below what exactly i am looking for.

[image: Given Image] .

For (e.g) above image i have as a layer (UIImageView), If i change the color of the OverCoat image that will change into the color what i set.

[image: After changing the color]

After changing the color simply it will look like the above.

Can someone please help me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this would be to use a mask image that defines which areas of the image should be tinted:

[image: Image tinted with mask]

This can be accomplished via `UIGraphicsImageRenderer`, see [Tinting an UIImage with a mask](https://www.ralfebert.de/ios/examples/image-processing/uiimage-tint-with-mask/) for an example playground.

```swift
import UIKit

let image = UIImage(named: "landscape.jpg")!
let mask = UIImage(named: "mask.png")!

let imageRenderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: image.size)

let tintedImage = imageRenderer.image { (ctx) in
    let cgContext = ctx.cgContext
    let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: image.size)
    image.draw(in: rect)
    cgContext.saveGState()
    cgContext.translateBy(x: 0, y: rect.size.height)
    cgContext.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0);
    cgContext.clip(to: rect, mask: mask.cgImage!)
    cgContext.setBlendMode(.color)
    UIColor.red.setFill()
    cgContext.fill(rect)
    cgContext.restoreGState()
}
```

Comment: I have tried, but this is not what i am looking for, When adjusting the tint of the UIImage it's not seems like an UIImage. I am not able to see the folds in the over coat. The image must be as same as image only the color should be changed.